How does does compiler know the definition of pre defined function even before linker haven't linked object file and library file?
We know that definition of pre defined functions are in library files, and it is the job of linker to link that library code(which is already compiled) to our object file (which has been created after compilation of our source code) but till then(before linker) compiler doesn't have the definition of pre defined functions so why doesn't it give any errors?
In the below C dummy program compiler gives the error undefined reference to `f1'obviously because it cannot find the function definition, but why doesn't the same applicable on pre defined functions. I mean they should give error too.
#include<stdio.h>

void f1();

int main()
{ 
    f1();
    return 0;
}


The compiler doesn't need the definition, just the declaration. The declaration is in header files like stdio.h.

By “pre defined function”, do you mean those specified in the C standard as standard library functions? Knowledge of them may be built into the compiler.

Give an example of a program containing a function you are asking about, not a program containing a different function. Would you take a friend’s car to the mechanic to ask them about a problem with your car at home?

Sir I am not asking about a specific program. Its a general question. I meant to say the definition of built in functions(like printf ) are in library files and as per I know linker links the library files code to the object file, but before then how does compiler which definition to bind with the function call. Is there some code in the header file itself which tells the compiler that the definition is present somewhere outside the source file?@EricPostpischil

Re. "...how does compiler which definition to bind": it doesn't -- that's the job of the  linker.

"In the below C dummy program compiler gives the error undefined reference to `f1'" -- not necessarily.  To avoid that, I simply need to include a library or object file that defines f1 in the link.

@HarshChaudhary: “I am not asking about a specific program“: Your post alleges the compiler will not give an error for a program using a “pre defined function.” If so, there is at least one program for which that is true. Show such a program. It does not matter if you are not asking about one specific program. The point is to show at least one example to make it clear what your question is. Also, answer the question about what you mean by a “pre defined function.”

To clarify what you actually mean: Do you mean "standard library functions defined by the C standard" when you use "predefined functions"? And do you mean the linker knowing where to find these functions without you specifying a library? In that case, normally a default library for these functions is automatically added by the linker.

@Gerhardh: Thanks, and what if the definition is present in the source code itself, then also does the linker do the binding of function call with its definition or compiler do this job(as compiler now can find the definition in the code). And yes by writing "pre defined functions" I mean the standard c library functions(like printf,scanf etc)

"The source itself" is a bit vague. In any serious project, "the source" consists of multiple C source files. Then yes, the linker will collect all the bits and pieces and all the stuff from libraries to one executable file.

The compiler does not give any error for the source code you posted. The linker will, if it can’t find f1().

A couple of things.

If you're actually getting an "undefined reference" message, it's probably from the linker. Maybe you're not telling the compiler to "just compile" the source. Check your compile options (cl /c, etc).
The compiler (when just doing its job: compiling) will include a reference to function "f1" into the object file. Later, the linker will bind these reference with the actual function with that name, which it'll look for inside another object file (whose name you'll supply in the command line), a library (idem, or in a default path), etc. There can be only ONE function with the same name. (Note: compilers of C++, when operating in C++ mode, where you can have several functions with the same name but different sets of parameters, will generate a unique name for each one of them. This is called "function name mangling".)
The compiler SHOULD know the function you're calling: its expected parameters, return type, etc. I'm not talking about the code itself, just the interface. For this reason, you SHOULD include the prototype to the called function in your code. In your example, that's the purpose of the line void f1();. Usually, this isn't done on a function-by-function basis, but using an #include directive (usually provided by the one who also wrote the function, for avoiding mistakes).

Edit (after rereading your question). If you're asking why THE LINKER doesn't show an "undefined reference" for the standard library functions, that's because of something I said in point 2: it looks for them (in fact, it looks for every referenced and yet undefined function) into a set of predefined libraries (in some given or default directory) (check your /LIBPATH option, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, etc, depending on your platform and compiler).

And if you're asking about WHICH specific function will be linked into the executable when you have more than one function with the same name, it depends. You may specify an order to the linker, using the command line, and/or it may use a predefined order (for standard libraries, etc).


In the below C dummy program compiler gives the error undefined reference to `f1'obviously because it cannot find the function definition, but why doesn't the same applicable on pre defined functions. I mean they should give error too.

When the compiler sees an include preprocessing directive, as in #include <stdio.h>, it replaces the directive by the entire contents of the header file.
The header file contains declarations of functions. C 2018 7.1.2 1 says:

… The header declares a set of related functions, plus any necessary types and additional macros needed to facilitate their use…

Thus, a program containing #include <stdio.h> contains a declaration of printf.


It will compile as the compiler does not need to know the function definition only the declaration to know how to call it and what the return type is: https://godbolt.org/z/nqr7GsePh

But you will not be able to link the executable as linker needs the object file containing this function : https://godbolt.org/z/fTbY8b8no


